# Problem with Samba/Raspberry/Nemo

Tags: samba, cinnamon, raspberrypi, nemo

Goodmorning everyone.
I have a problem with the 'windows network' in Nemo (default cinnamon file manager).
I configured samba on raspberrypi with Raspbian.
From a client with Ubuntu 18.10 and cinnamon I can see the connection using 'connect to the server ...' and entering the ip address of the raspberry, but if I try to use the menu item of Nemo: 'File / Network' and in the right panel I select the 'Windows Network' icon I see NOTHING.
I hope someone can explain where I'm wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Samba network discovery for NetBIOS hosts has issues as described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1778322?comments=all

The Good News: Linux and MacOS machines do not have to use NetBIOS for host discovery. It can be replaced with Avahi.

Make sure avahi-daemon is installed on the Pi:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

Make sure it's running:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon status
```

Create a file on the Pi at: `/etc/avahi/services/samba.service`

With this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
   <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h SMB</name> ## Display Name
   <service>
       <type>_smb._tcp</type>
       <port>445</port>
   </service>
</service-group>
```

You may need to restart the daemon: `sudo service avahi-daemon restart`

Nemo will show the Pi under Network but not under Windows Network since it's not using the Windows discovery protocol.